# Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'

Tags: r, ggmap

I am getting this error in R when I try to run the function route() within a loop:

Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'

The function is found in the package "ggmap". It takes two strings as an argument and searches on google maps the directions between them. It returns a dataframe which contains information about the route including distance, minutes, coordinates etc.

I have a vector with many strings which represent postcodes and I am using this route() function within a loop on those postcodes. It runs ok for the first 40 or so searches, but then it crashes giving the above error.

```
df <- as.data.frame(read.csv("df.csv", sep=","))

for (i in df$post_code){
  route(i,'NE29 8NH', structure = 'route', mode = 'driving')
}
```

I checked the vector with postcodes and there are no missing values or other anomalies. Please help me with this.

Comment: can we see some data please?

Comment: This is the structure of the postcodes vector:

chr [1:2102] "NE48 2SG" "NE43 7QP" "NE46 3NB" "NE46 3AL" "NE46 2BD" "NE46 2EZ" "NE49 9AJ" "NE42 6JU" "NE46 1PU" "NE45 5PJ" ...

Comment: `route` help says `from =  "name of origin addresses in a data frame (vector accepted)"`, so why are you using a loop?

Comment: Because if I try to give the vector as an argument, it only calculates the direction for the first value of the vector (i.e. for the first postcode)

Comment: The strange thing I have just noticed is that every time I try to run the loop it fails after a different number of searches. Maybe it ahs to do with the fact that Google may be blocking the access for sending too many requests at once? But then, why that error?

Comment: After the call to `route`, and before the end closing brace, insert a call to `browser()` and run it again. It will tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue has to do with google maps rate limits, just enter the request URL and refresh the browser a few times and you will get the below message:

```
{
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your rate-limit for this API.",
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

ggmaps tries to parse the json response, but the response doesn't have any information.  I would suggest forcing a delay in your loop with Sys.sleep(x), x<-seconds.