# Using route function on multiple addresses in ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

I would like to calculate the route between multiple addresses using the route function in ggmap. I came up with 2 alternative solutions, but both don't work:

*alternative 1

First I made 2 vectors: one with points of interest (4 in total) and another one with the base address.

```
points_of_interest <- c(
"berlin",
"paris",
"new york",
"madrid")

base_address <- "helsinki"
```

The following should calculate the exact route between each pair of points_of_interest and base_address. So a total of 4 routes: berlin - helsinki, paris - helsinki, new york - helsinki and madrid - helsinki.

```
calculatedroutes1 <- route(from = base_address,
                          to = points_of_interest)
```

The problem is I only get the route for berlin-helsinki, although I thought it should be vectorized.

*alternative 2

Since `route` didn't seem to vectorize I thought maybe I could use plyr. So this was my alternative code:

```
 df.routes <- data.frame(points_of_interest,
                         rep(base_address, each = length(points_of_interest),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 df. calculatedroutes2 <- ddply(.data = df.routes,
                           .variables = .(points_of_interest, base_address),
                           .fun = route,
                           points_of_interest,
                           base_address)
```

For each combination of points_of_interest and base_address (so for all 4 routes) I wanted to use the function `route` with arguments `from = points_of_interest` and `to = base_address`. This generated the error `Error: unexpected ',' in "points_of_interest,` but I think this is the right way to add arguments to a function in ddply?

Another question which is similar to mine [other error route function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083512/error-list-object-cannot-be-coerced-to-type-integer) is still unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code for `route(...)` (just type "route" at the command line, no `?` or `()`), this function is **not** vectorized, although the documentation suggests it is.

`route(...)` uses the Google Directions API, which takes a single origin and a single destination. If you pass a vector in the `to=...` argument, `route(...)` creates a vector of urls, but only uses the first one.

One way around this uses the `Vectorize(...)` function in R:

```
rt <- Vectorize(route,vectorize.args=c("from","to"),SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
rt(base_address,points_of_interest)
```

This, too will fail with your definitions for `points_of_interest`, because Google Directions supports three mode of transport: driving, bicycle, and walk, and none of these will get you from Helsinki to NY. If you remove `new york` from points of interest, you get a list of data frames with the routes from Helsinki to each of the other cities.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I was indeed confused by the help function of route which explicitly mentioned 'vector accepted' which strongly suggested vectorization should be possible. Just for the sake of completeness, any idea why the second alternative didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

This generated the error Error: unexpected ',' in "points_of_interest, but I think this is the right way to add arguments to a function in ddply?

I guess you should put those arguments between quotes:

```
df. calculatedroutes2 <- ddply(.data = df.routes,
                       .variables = .(points_of_interest, base_address),
                       .fun = route,
                       "points_of_interest",
                       "base_address")
```